# Texto a color en python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Para usar secuencias de código **ANSI** y generar texto a color desde la terminal tengo entendido que es algo como:

`texto = '\x1b[94mtexto a color\x1b[0m'`

así al llamar la función imprime a color el texto

`print(texto)`

Ahora, hice un diccionario para solo elegir una llave y que me diera un color al azar, pues quiero cambiar el color del texto en una lista, el problema es que no me cambia el color, sino que me pega tal cual el texto, es decir, en lugar de imprimir *'texto'* a color, me imprime tal cual la cadena:

`'\x1b[94mtexto a color\x1b[0m'`

Supongo que esto tiene que ver con la funcion `print()` que de alguna manera ya interpreta el carácter escape `"\\x"`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que genere color y no el texto tal cual?

```
import random

# Colores para distinguir un poco 
colores = {
    0 : '\033[0m',   # color default
    1 : '\033[93m',  # amarillo
    2 : '\033[94m',  # azul
    3 : '\033[95m',  # morado
    4 : '\033[91m',  # rojo
    5 : '\033[92m'}  # verde


# Elegir al azar
def color_azahar():
    """Elige un color al azar en un diccionario de colores"""
    indice = random.randint(0, len(colores)-1)
    return colores[indice]

def imprime_bonito(arreglo):
    """Dado un arreglo de nxn imprime cada renglón para que se vea legible"""
    for i in range(len(arreglo)):
        print(arreglo[i])


def cambia(cuadri, n):
    
    if n == 1: 
        return cuadri
    if n == 2:       #  [[a, ]
        #caso donde        , ], 
        if cuadri[0][0] == 'a': 
            #sacamos el color 
            ado = color_azahar()+'a'+colores[0]
            #coloreamos los demás
            cuadri[0][1] = str(ado)
            cuadri[1][0] = ado
            cuadri[1][1] = ado
        return cuadri

prueba = [['a', ' '],['','']] 
imprime_bonito(cambia(prueba, 2)) # no imprime con color, sino el texto tal cual

texto = color_azahar()+'a'+colores[0] # aquí sí lo imprime bien 
print(texto)
```

Comment: No te lo imprime bien porque estás mandando a imprimir una lista, no una cadena. Ese truco solo funciona para cadenas. Para lo que quieres sustituye `print(arreglo[i])` por `print("[" + ','.join(arreglo[i]) + "]")` dentro de la función `imprime_bonito`. Yo te recomendaría usar [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/), que está hecho específicamente para ello.

Comment: Un poco tarde, pero: no está demás aclarar que *azar* = aleatoriedad (en este caso) y *azahar* = flor :)

Answer (score -1):

La función `imprime_bonito` recibe una lista de listas. Tienes que convertir cada sublista en un texto antes de imprimirlo. Para eso puedes usar `join()`.

```
def imprime_bonito(arreglo):
    """Dado un arreglo de nxn imprime cada renglón para que se vea legible"""
    for sublista in arreglo:
        linea = ''.join(sublista)
        print(linea)
```